# Programatically convert numeric strings in Excel spread sheet to actual numbers

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, excel-2010

I have some C# code which programatically loops over all the cells in the spread sheet and convert any numeric string values to actual numbers.
It seems to work, but it runs fairly slow(on a spread sheet with 40 columns by 3000 rows, it takes over a minute to run):

```
private void SetNumberStringsToValues(Excel.Range range)
  {
     object[,] values = range.get_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);

     Parallel.For(1, range.Columns.Count, i =>
     {
        for (var j = 1; j < range.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
           var doubleValue = 0.0;
           if (double.TryParse(values[j, i].ToString(), out doubleValue))
              values[j, i] = doubleValue;
        }
     });
     range.set_Value(Excel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, values);
  }
```

Does anyone know a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: If Excel uses a 1-based index, then does this algorithm process the last row and/or column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try caching the number of rows instead of calling range.Rows.Count inside the loop.  There may be some internal synchronization in the `range` instance that will come under contention when accessed from multiple threads.

Also, I'm curious why you start your enumeration at 1 instead of 0?  Won't that miss the first row and column?

```
...

var columns = range.Columns.Count;
var rows = range.Rows.Count;

Parallel.For(1, columns + 1, i => 
{ 
   for (var j = 1; j <= rows; j++) 
   { 
      var doubleValue = 0.0; 
      if (double.TryParse(values[j, i].ToString(), out doubleValue)) 
         values[j, i] = doubleValue; 
   } 
});

...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That does the trick. Second pair of eyes always helps:)

Comment: Seems that if I make the index 0-based instead of 1-based, i get an index out of range exception

Comment: Ya, could be that the underlying excel COM object is using 1-based array indices, in which case I believe you will need to increment `rows` and `columns` by 1 in order to make sure you get the last row and column.